# How do I suppress the Spotbugs stacktrace in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, spotbugs

I'm setting up Spotbugs in a Gradle project but when I run it, Spotbugs does generate the output report but logs a failure stacktrace to the console. I'm wondering if there is a way to suppress it.

Here's my Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs.snom:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:4.0.5"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "com.github.spotbugs"

group 'com.mridang'
version '1.1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.9

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

spotbugs {
    toolVersion = '4.0.2'
    ignoreFailures = true
}

spotbugsMain {
    ignoreFailures = true
}

spotbugsTest {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

When I run Gradle, I get the following error:

```
> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :spotbugsMain
SpotBugs reported failures
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Verification failed: SpotBugs violation found: 5
        at com.github.spotbugs.snom.internal.SpotBugsRunnerForWorker$SpotBugsExecutor.execute(SpotBugsRunnerForWorker.java:97)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.execute(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:84)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:129)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:126)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

> Task :spotbugsTest
SpotBugs reported failures
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Verification failed: SpotBugs violation found: 3
        at com.github.spotbugs.snom.internal.SpotBugsRunnerForWorker$SpotBugsExecutor.execute(SpotBugsRunnerForWorker.java:97)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.execute(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:84)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:129)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:126)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

> Task :test
...
...
```

[Based on the sources](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/spotbugs/snom/internal/SpotBugsRunnerForWorker.java#L102), it seems that it is possible to change this behavior by passing `ignoreFailures` but I can't seem to get that working

Comment: Are you sure you are not using `-s` on the CLI? This is the short form of `--stacktrace` which will make Gradle print the stacktrace of errors. Otherwise, stacktraces should not be printed to the console by Gradle.

Comment: I updated SpotBugs to the latest v4 (was using v2) and latest Gradle (v6.4) and now I also get this. `ignoreFailures` causes the task not to fail the build, but it still prints this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't suppress the stacktrace, it's part of the log call:

```
        if (params.getIgnoreFailures().getOrElse(Boolean.FALSE).booleanValue()) {
          log.warn("SpotBugs reported failures", e);
        } else {
          throw e;
        }
```

See https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/spotbugs/snom/internal/SpotBugsRunnerForWorker.java#L107 for full context.

I created https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/issues/266 as i was looking for the same

Comment: Thx Chris. It isn't a blocker but made the output so much more unreadable.

Answer (score 5):

Stacktrace suppression in spotbugs can be achieved by adding showStackTraces directive with value false into spotbugs task (default is true).

According to your build.gradle file, your spotbugs definition has to be:

```
spotbugs {
    toolVersion = '4.0.2'
    ignoreFailures = true
    showStackTraces = false
}
```

More information [here](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin#readme).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was using two different blocks of try-catch. Had one block in the middle but nothing throws in the main class. also some blocks inside the main block.
when I remove the main block it built successfully. Part of the error message was:

`<ShortMessage>Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown</ShortMessage>`